# Order of update column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, update

This is my Table Employee. Reocrds like  below

```
id  first_name  last_name   salary  start_Date  region  city
1   VINOTH  Martin  5890.00 2005-03-22 00:00:00.000 North   CHENNAI
2   BALU    Mathews 4789.00 2003-07-21 00:00:00.000 South   MUMBAI
3   James   Smith   6678.00 2001-12-01 00:00:00.000 North   Paris
4   Celia   Rice    5567.00 2006-03-03 00:00:00.000 South   London
5   Robert  Black   4467.00 2004-07-02 00:00:00.000 East    Newton
6   Linda   Green   6456.00 2002-05-19 00:00:00.000 East    Calgary
7   David   Larry   5345.00 2008-03-18 00:00:00.000 West    New York
8   James   Cat 4234.00 2007-07-17 00:00:00.000 West    Regina
9   Joan    Act 6123.00 2001-04-16 00:00:00.000 North   Toronto



update employee set city='CHENNAI',  first_name='VINOTH' where id=1

update employee set first_name='BALU',  city='MUMBAI' where id=2
```

Which one is faster?

Comment: Do you really mean 2000 columns? Or 2000 rows?

Comment: Scenario1: For Example first update FIRSTCOLUMN record then update LASTTCOLUMN   Scenario2: For Example first update LASTCOLUMN record then update FIRSTCOLUMN Any Difference for TWO Statement

Comment: uhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh ... you'd be the person most likely to be able to answer that

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any scenario where the order of columns in your UPDATE statement will have any impact on performance. Of course, this is something you could test.

I also can't imagine any scenario where it's a good idea for a single table to have 2,000 columns.

Comment: Example first update last column record then update first_column record  any difference.

Comment: @Vinoth_S You will need to clarify. The two examples you gave in the question had one where you updated city first, then first name, and the other where you updated first name first, then city. What "order of update statement" are you talking about exactly? Order of *what*?

Answer (score 1):

For speed of your query as shown, the primary impact on performance would be whether or not you have an index (which should probably be either a `primary key` or else `unique`) on `id`.  That index would allow a seek to the row that needs to be updated.

With regard to column order `city` or `first_name` for the two updates in your sample, there is no difference.  You should view the two column changes on a row as happening *all at once*.

Furthermore, just for clarity, if your update changed many rows, you still should view the changes as happening *all at once*.  (Though it could take a longer time, of course.)